# Como adicionar elementos concretos em runtime no padrão de projeto visitor?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao *Design Pattern **Visitor***.

Pelos meus estudos, se você quiser adicionar um novo elemento concreto ao padrão deve adicionar um novo método abstrato na interface do visitor e implementar esse método nos visitors concretos. Isso requer que o software esteja parado, ser recompilado... enfim.

Há alguma variação de implementação deste padrão onde seja possível adicionar novos elementos concretos em `runtime`, como plugin, por exemplo?

Answer (score 3):

Talvez seja suficiente criar um método que sirva para visitar qualquer objeto que implemente uma interface, ao invés do tipo concreto final. Dessa forma, um único método abstrato seria responsável por visitar vários tipos de objetos concretos que implementem aquela interface, inclusive objetos importados via plug-in.

Dessa forma é possível adicionar mais tipos dinamicamente, entretanto limitaria o trabalho do método, que trabalharia sobre a interface e não sobre o tipo concreto... essa limitação pode ser contornada fazendo a interface com um método `Accept` que toma um objeto visitor, e é capaz de passar sub-objetos para o visitor.

**Exemplo em C#:**

```cs
class Concrete
{
}

/// <summary>
/// Interface de plug-in que pode ser visitada por um Visitor.
/// </summary>
interface IPlugin
{
    void Accept(Visitor visitor);
}

class Plugin1 : IPlugin
{
    public Concrete Concrete { get; set; }

    public void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this.Concrete);
    }
}

abstract class Visitor
{
    public void Visit(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Concrete)
            this.Visit(obj as Concrete);
        else if (obj is IPlugin)
            this.Visit(obj as IPlugin);
    }

    public abstract void Visit(Concrete concrete);

    public virtual void Visit(IPlugin plugin)
    {
        plugin.Accept(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Miguel. Interessante sua solução, mas não entendi como posso contornar o fato deste único método visitante trabalhar sobre uma interface e não sobre um tipo concreto.

Comment: Tudo o que você quiser com o tipo concreto terá de ser feito através da interface, pois o método visitante só conhece a interface. Por exemplo, se houver uma propriedade `Nome` nos plugins e você quiser alterar o nome, então essa propriedade terá de constar na interface `IPlugin` e implementada em todas as classes concretar que implementem a mesma.

Comment: Mas e se eu adicionar um novo elemento com atributos particulares e quiser manipulá-los a partir da implementação desse visit()? No way?

Comment: Não será possível ao método visitante manipular partes do objeto concreto que não conhece. O que se pode fazer é implementar na interface métodos para listar e manipular tais atributos, via string, ou usar reflexão (ai depende da linguagem).